# What happens after Apple Developer License expires?

Tags: ios

What happens if I don't renew my apple developer account? Will I be able to create new provisioning profiles or develop,run and test apps locally without submitting them to the app store?

Comment: You will still be able to develop applications and test on the local device (check the "Sign in with Apple ID" section)
 https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: I think this is the right answer , can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still be able to develop applications and test on the local device (check the "Sign in with Apple ID" section)

https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ### Expired memberships
>
> If your Apple Developer Program membership expires, your apps will no
> longer be available for download and you won’t be able to submit new
> apps or updates. You’ll lose access to prerelease software,
> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, and TSIs. However, your apps
> will still function for users who have already installed or downloaded
> them, and you will still have access to App Store Connect and free
> development resources.
>
> If your Apple Developer Enterprise Program membership expires, your
> apps will no longer be available for download and they’ll no longer
> function for those who have already installed or downloaded them. You
> will, however, still have access to free development resources.
>
> Thirty days before membership expiration, you’ll have the option to
> download a copy of your registered test device list and/or opt in to
> have all devices removed immediately upon expiration if you don’t plan
> to renew membership. If you don’t opt in, all devices will be removed
> automatically 180 days after membership expiration.
>
> iOS Developer University Program memberships don’t expire.

https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/

Comment: Thanks, so it means I also can't create and test new apps on my local device, right?